# Is there a faster implementation of the following code?

Tags: python, performance, loops, numpy, vectorization

I have a one-dimensional `numpy` array, which is quite large in size. For each entry of the array, I need to produce a linearly spaced sub-array upto that entry value. Here is what I have as an example.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 3])
b = np.array([np.linspace(0, i, 4) for i in a])
```

In this case there is linear space of size 4. The last statement in the above code involves a `for loop` which is rather slow if `a` is very large. Is there a trick to implement this in `numpy` itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can phrase this as an [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product):

```
In [37]: a = np.arange(100000)

In [38]: %timeit np.array([np.linspace(0, i, 4) for i in a])
1 loop, best of 3: 1.3 s per loop

In [39]: %timeit np.outer(a, np.linspace(0, 1, 4))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop
```

The idea is to a take a unit `linspace` and then scale it separately by each element of `a`.

As you can see, this gives ~1000x speed up for `n=100000`.

For completeness, I'll mention that this code has slightly different roundoff properties than your original version (likely not an issue in practical applications):

```
In [52]: np.max(np.abs(np.array([np.linspace(0, i, 4) for i in a]) -
    ...:               np.outer(a, np.linspace(0, 1, 4))))
Out[52]: 1.4551915228366852e-11
```

P. S. An alternative way to express the idea is by using element-wise multiplication with broadcasting (based on a suggestion by @Scott Gigante):

```
In [55]: %timeit a[:, np.newaxis] * np.linspace(0, 1, 4)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 ms per loop
```

P. P. S. See the comments below for further ideas on making this faster.

Comment: You can set the `dtype` of np.linspace to avoid unnecessary conversion (if double precision is not required and input is single precision)

Comment: BTW since `linspace(0, 1, 4)` starts from zero and ends with one, the two columns actually do not need to be computed at all (just initialize an empty array, output the product result to other columns, and fill the first column with zero, last column with the input).

Comment: About rounding effect :`np.outer(a/3,arange(4))` is exactly  `np.array([np.linspace(0, i, 4) for i in a])`.  And `u=a/3;w=np.vstack([np.zeros(a.size),u,2*u,a]).T` is twice faster.